# Trading System with Akka

Tags: java, akka

Recently I did an exercise to understand Akka. I implemented a trading system with Akka to process orders with Actors.

My code is like:

Order: Immutable class with acts as the messages in the system.

```
public final class Order {

    public enum OrderType {
        BUY,
        SELL
    };

    private final int orderId;

    private final OrderType orderType;

    private final String instrument;

    private final double price;

    public Order(int orderId, OrderType orderType, String instrument, double price) {
        this.orderId = orderId;
        this.orderType = orderType;
        this.instrument = instrument;
        this.price = price;
    }

    public int getOrderId() {
        return orderId;
    }

    public OrderType getOrderType() {
        return orderType;
    }

    public String getInstrument() {
        return instrument;
    }

    public double getPrice() {
        return price;
    }
}
```

Then I created an `OrderProcessingActor` to process the orders received. For now, the process is an abstract thing which only prints the order received and tells the sender order executed information.

```
import akka.actor.AbstractActor;
import akka.actor.Props;

public class OrderProcessingActor extends AbstractActor {

    public static Props props() {
        return Props.create(OrderProcessingActor.class, OrderProcessingActor::new);
    }

    @Override
    public Receive createReceive() {
        return receiveBuilder()
                .match(
                        Order.class,
                        order -> {
                            processOrder(order);
                        }).build();
    }

    private void processOrder(Order order) {
        System.out.println(String.format("OrderProcessingActor %d %s order received for instrument %s with price %s", order.getOrderId(), order.getOrderType(), order.getInstrument(), order.getPrice()));
        //process order here.
        getSender().tell(String.format("OrderProcessingActor %d %s order processed for instrument %s with price %s", order.getOrderId(), order.getOrderType(), order.getInstrument(), order.getPrice()), getSelf());
    }
}
```

I also created a `TradingSystemSupervisor` which is responsible for creating and managing `OrderProcessingActor`. The orders are received by the `TradingSystemSupervisor` which are then sent to the `OrderProcessingActor`.

```
import akka.actor.AbstractActor;
import akka.actor.ActorRef;
import akka.actor.Props;

import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;


public class TradingSystemSupervisor extends AbstractActor {

    private static Map<String, ActorRef> actorRefMap = new HashMap<>();

    public static Props props() {
        return Props.create(TradingSystemSupervisor.class, TradingSystemSupervisor::new);
    }

    @Override
    public Receive createReceive() {
        return receiveBuilder()
                .match(
                        Order.class,
                        order -> {processOrder(order);}).build();
    }

    private void processOrder(Order order) {
        System.out.println(String.format("TradingSystemSupervisor %d, %s order received for instrument %s with price %s", order.getOrderId(), order.getOrderType(), order.getInstrument(), order.getPrice()));
        //process order here.
        if(!actorRefMap.containsKey(order.getInstrument())) {
            ActorRef actorRef = getContext().getSystem().actorOf(OrderProcessingActor.props(), String.format("%s-order-processing-actor", order.getInstrument()));
            actorRefMap.put(order.getInstrument(), actorRef);
        }
        actorRefMap.get(order.getInstrument()).tell(order, getSelf());
    }
}
```

I am looking for a review of the solution from Java as well as Akka's perspective. Is my solution ok considering the way I have used Akka or can I improve the solution? I am also trying to implement Akka routing to this solution.

Answer (score 1):

Other than maybe adding some comments for documentation, this seems pretty sane. This:

```
    System.out.println(String.format("OrderProcessingActor %d %s order received for instrument %s with price %s", order.getOrderId(), order.getOrderType(), order.getInstrument(), order.getPrice()));
    //process order here.
    getSender().tell(String.format("OrderProcessingActor %d %s order processed for instrument %s with price %s", order.getOrderId(), order.getOrderType(), order.getInstrument(), order.getPrice()), getSelf());
```

is a classic don't-repeat-yourself situation. Make a `toString()` method on `Order`:

```
String toString() {
   return String.format("OrderProcessingActor %d %s order for instrument %s with price %f", orderId, orderType, instrument, price);
}
```

Then, the prior code can be

```
    System.out.println(String.format("%s has been received", order));
    //process order here.
    getSender().tell(String.format("%s has been processed", order));
```